# Estimating cost to publish a contract

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, brownie

I'm close to publishing a contract to the Ethereum mainnet after a couple of months of publishing contracts to Rinkeby. I just want to try and estimate how much it will cost me to publish it to mainnet. I'm using brownie, and when I publish to brownie, it gives me an output that will be something like `Gas price: 1.282474412 gwei | Gas used: 2685256`

If the gas used was 2685256, to estimate now much it will cost to publish that contract, assuming it is unchanged, would I multiply 2685256 by the current gas price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes :) Current gas price being 100 gwei for example.

Comment: Thanks, right you were. Contract published and I didn't go broke!

Comment:  glad to hear